# Jetpack Compose Getting Light vs Dark Mode from MaterialTheme Using Material 3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

With Jetpack Compose, using Material 2, you can see if a theme is in light mode easily with the following

```
val light = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight
```

Using Material 3, I don't see this ability. Is there a way to do this with a Material 3 theme?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a solution. `Color` in Compose has a built in method `luminance` that returns the relative luminance as a float between 0 and 1. I wrote an extension function for `ColorScheme` that returns true if the luminance of the background is greater than 0.5.

```
@Composable
fun ColorScheme.isLight() = this.background.luminance() > 0.5
```

Using it as:

```
val isLight = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.isLight()
```

Now whether the system is in dark mode doesn't matter, only the theme.

Comment: Is there a special reason to write it as a composable function instead of a property, which would make it easier to migrate old code?

Comment: It's not about light/dark color theme really... some apps can have dark color backgrounds in light theme also... bad solution.

Comment: @realh because I wanted a composable function.

Comment: @Demigod got a better solution then?

Answer (score 8):

In JetpackCompose you can use this method that returns if the light / dark mode is enabled or not

```
isSystemInDarkTheme()
```

And then in your code

```
if (isSystemInDarkTheme()){} \\Dark mode enabled
else {} //Light mode enabled
```

Comment: I'm using that as a workaround, but the theme could be light or dark independently of the system, so I was hoping for some method to see that.