# How to declare colors based on dark theme enabled or not, in compose with material 3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-dark-theme

in my app, I have some custom colors and I use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71594753/4205927) to know if the dark theme is enabled but there are some colors I want to make global based on the dark theme to use it from any composable fun in the project

This example of my colors **topAppBarBackgroundColor** and **topAppBarContentColor** declared in each composable and I am looking for a solution to make it global in Color.kt file to avoid repeated codes

```
@Composable
fun ListAppBar(
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
    searchAppbarState: SearchAppbarState,
    searchTextState: String
) {

    when (searchAppbarState) {
        SearchAppbarState.CLOSED -> {
            DefaultListAppBar(
                onSearchClicked = {
                    sharedViewModel.searchAppbarState.value = SearchAppbarState.OPENED
                },
                onSortClicked = {},
                onDeleteClicked = {}
            )
        }

        else -> {
            SearchAppBar(
                text = searchTextState,
                onTextChange = {newText->
                    sharedViewModel.searchTextState.value = newText
                },
                onCloseClicked = {
                    sharedViewModel.searchAppbarState.value = SearchAppbarState.CLOSED
                    sharedViewModel.searchTextState.value = ""
                }) {

            }
        }
    }


}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DefaultListAppBar(
    onSearchClicked: () -> Unit,
    onSortClicked: (Priority) -> Unit,
    onDeleteClicked: () -> Unit
) {


    val isLight = rememberSaveable() {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    isLight.value = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.isLight()


    val topAppBarContentColor: Color = if (isLight.value)
        Color.White else Color.LightGray

    val topAppBarBackgroundColor: Color = if (isLight.value)
        Purple500 else Color.Black

    TopAppBar(title = {
        Text(
            text = "Tasks",
            color = topAppBarContentColor
        )
    },
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
            containerColor = topAppBarBackgroundColor
        ),

        actions = {
            ListAppBarActions(
                onSearchClicked = onSearchClicked,
                onSortClicked = onSortClicked,
                onDeleteClicked = {}
            )
        }

    )
}

@Composable
fun ListAppBarActions(
    onSearchClicked: () -> Unit,
    onSortClicked: (Priority) -> Unit,
    onDeleteClicked: () -> Unit
) {

    SearchAction(onSearchClicked = onSearchClicked)

    SortAction(onSortClicked = onSortClicked)

    DeleteAllAction(onDeleteClicked = onDeleteClicked)
}

@Composable
fun SearchAction(onSearchClicked: () -> Unit) {

    val isLight = rememberSaveable() {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    isLight.value = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.isLight()


    val topAppBarContentColor: Color = if (isLight.value)
        Color.White else Color.LightGray

    val topAppBarBackgroundColor: Color = if (isLight.value)
    Purple500 else Color.Black

    IconButton(
        onClick = onSearchClicked
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search,
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.search_tasks),
            tint = topAppBarContentColor
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun SortAction(onSortClicked: (Priority) -> Unit) {

    val isLight = rememberSaveable() {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    isLight.value = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.isLight()


    val topAppBarContentColor: Color = if (isLight.value)
        Color.White else Color.LightGray

    var expanded by remember() {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    IconButton(onClick = { expanded = true }) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_filter_list_24),
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.sort_tasks),
            tint = topAppBarContentColor
        )

        DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
            DropdownMenuItem(text = { PriorityItem(priority = Priority.LOW) },
                onClick = {
                    expanded = false
                    onSortClicked(Priority.LOW)
                })

            DropdownMenuItem(text = { PriorityItem(priority = Priority.HIGH) },
                onClick = {
                    expanded = false
                    onSortClicked(Priority.HIGH)
                })

            DropdownMenuItem(text = { PriorityItem(priority = Priority.NONE) },
                onClick = {
                    expanded = false
                    onSortClicked(Priority.NONE)
                })
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun DeleteAllAction(onDeleteClicked: () -> Unit) {
    val isLight = rememberSaveable() {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    isLight.value = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.isLight()


    val topAppBarContentColor: Color = if (isLight.value)
        Color.White else Color.LightGray

    var expanded by remember() {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    IconButton(onClick = { expanded = true }) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_more_vert_24),
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.delete_all),
            tint = topAppBarContentColor
        )

        DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
            DropdownMenuItem(
                text = {

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = LARGE_PADDING),
                        text = stringResource(R.string.delete_all),
                        style = Typography.headlineSmall
                    )
                },
                onClick = {
                    expanded = false
                    onDeleteClicked()
                }
            )
        }

    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SearchAppBar(
    text: String,
    onTextChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onCloseClicked: () -> Unit,
    onSearchClicked: (String) -> Unit
) {


    val isLight = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    isLight.value = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.isLight()


    val topAppBarBackgroundColor: Color = if (isLight.value)
        Purple500 else Color.Black

    val topAppBarContentColor: Color = if (isLight.value)
        Color.White else Color.LightGray


    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(56.dp),
        color = topAppBarBackgroundColor

    ) {
        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {
                onTextChange(it)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Transparent),
            placeholder = {
                Text(
                    text = "Search here...",
                    modifier = Modifier.alpha(0.3F),
                    color = Color.White,
                )

            },
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium.fontSize
            ),
            singleLine = true,
            leadingIcon = {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {},
                    modifier = Modifier.alpha(0.5F)
                ) {

                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.search_icon),
                        tint = Color.White
                    )

                }
            },
            trailingIcon = {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                            onTextChange("")
                        } else {
                            onCloseClicked()
                        }
                    }
                ) {

                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Close,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.close_icon),
                        tint = Color.White
                    )

                }
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Search
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onSearch = {
                    onSearchClicked(text)
                }
            ),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                textColor = Color.White,
                containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                cursorColor = topAppBarContentColor,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            )
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make pretty much the same thing as with isLight() extension function - make it an extension function/property of `ColorScheme`:

```kotlin
fun ColorScheme.isLight() = this.background.luminance() > 0.5

val ColorScheme.topAppBarBackgroundColor: Color get() {
    return if (isLight()) Purple500 else Color.Black
}

val ColorScheme.topAppBarContentColor: Color get() {
    return if (isLight()) Color.White else Color.LightGray
}
```

you can then use it just like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DefaultListAppBar() {
    val contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.topAppBarContentColor
}
```

---

On a side note, `isLight()` doesn't have to be a `@Composable` function (and shouldn't be then), same as the newly declared `topAppBarBackgroundColor` and `topAppBarContentColor`.
Also, it doesn't make any sense to create that `isLight` `MutableState` you did:

```kotlin
val isLight = rememberSaveable() {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}

isLight.value = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.isLight()
```

you create `MutableState` here but then you update it in every recomposition, so it is equivalent to simply doing `val isLight = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.isLight()`

Comment: I removed `@Composable` from `isLight` method and everything worked as expected, Thanks